# Add a view to the bottom in AQGridView in iOS

Tags: ios, aqgridview

I'm using `AQGridView` to show a grid image, now I want to load more data -> finish. But I want to insert `UIActivityIndicatorView` when scrolling to the bottom of `AQGridView` and I don't know how to achieve this.

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this without **XIB** it will be very difficult for you but you can create a view controller with Xib file to Create the interface of your choice. [Here is the Video of how it can be done in the best possible way](http://vimeo.com/46408155) by  `Evadne Wu`. And [here](https://github.com/evadne/gridViewNibTest) is the Sample Project